# Web server options for Ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, webserver

I wanted to know which is the best web server to use with heroku running ruby 2.0.

I'm currently running puma but cannot take full advantage of it without rubinius or jruby. I don't want to change my interpreter from ruby 2.0 native.

My goal is to have a web server that scales efficiently as I scale up my heroku dynos.. Thus, helping me serve as many concurrent users as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the decision is if your application is considered thread safe. 
**Out of the box Rails < 4.0 is not!** If you want it to work on multiple requests at the same time, you need a server that is capable of forking. Most prominent example: [Unicorn](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/2/27/unicorn_rails). Heroku suggests that for Rails apps.

However, if your app is not limiting itself to one thread:

**I suggest to use puma**. It does support multiple threads on a single dyno. Even with MRI. 
As said on [pumas official website](http://puma.io/) it uses significantly less memory than unicorn.

I honestly don't know what you mean by "cannot take full advantage". The only problem you might run into is, independent of the platform it runs on, that your application is thread safe.

> My goal is to have a web server that scales efficiently as I scale up my heroku dynos.. Thus, helping me serve as many concurrent users as possible.

Once you spin up multiple dynos, the webservers will be started on each dyno independent of each other. I don't see any special needs for this scenario.

Comment: So any other reasons for using puma? By full advantage .. I mean running multiple threads without the GIL in MRI .

Comment: Edited my answer to include the somewhat bogus memory footprint comparison of puma vs. unicorn. It really depends on your app...

Comment: I'm little not agree Rails < 4.0 is not threadsafe. Take this article: http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html Rails itself is threadsafe, but you have to follow some recommendations to make your APP thread safe.

Comment: @GaborGarami, yep, thanks for pointing out this unclear wording of mine. :-)